# Can't connect to to hc-08 bluetooth module with android

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, hc-05

I tried to connect to the HC-08 Bluetooth module many times but at first, I can't pair module to android and I connect the module to android with [Bluetooth Electronics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keuwl.arduinobluetooth&hl=en_US) but after the module, I paired I have another issue. I got the below error when I'm tried to connect with the module how can I solve the problem?

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the HC-08 Bluetooth module works with Bluetooth Low Energy while the Bluetooth Electronics app works with the HC-05 module which is Bluetooth BR/EDR (aka classic). These two are not compatible with each other.

According to: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4urklB65vaCcmFqOGRFWV9IR2s/view

The UUID's used by this module are:

Service: "0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb”

Characteristic: “0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb”

I find the nRF Connect app very good for testing these kinds of modules. Or if you have the Chrome or Chromium browser installed on your PC, Phone, or Raspberry Pi, then you can do it from there if you enter the URL of:

chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices

Press `Start Scan` -> `Inspect` the device -> click on `0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` service -> click on `0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` characteristic

You should now be able to read and write values.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but I can't connect to the JDY-08 Bluetooth with chrome

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15h2gp8LrmBSwtS3es9AaBIscHmZjutjy/view?usp=sharing this is an image from my chrome

Comment: Thanks for the picture. It shows the ”connect" in the top right. This means your disconnected. Connect again and you should have read and write

Comment: sorry I send value to the bluetooth with able scanner with your way thanks for your help